# The best way to search a file and return required fields from rows

Tags: python, file, csv, search

I have the following code that works perfectly. It searches a txt file for an ID number, and if it exists, returns the first and last name.

full listing: https://repl.it/Jau3/0

```
import csv

#==========Search by ID number. Return Just the Name Fields for the Student
with open("studentinfo.txt","r") as f:
  studentfileReader=csv.reader(f)
  id=input("Enter Id:")
  for row in studentfileReader:
    for field in row:
      if field==id:
        currentindex=row.index(id)
        print(row[currentindex+1]+" "+row[currentindex+2])
```

**File contents**

```
001,Joe,Bloggs,Test1:99,Test2:100,Test3:33
002,Ash,Smith,Test1:22,Test2:63,Test3:99
```

For teaching and learning purposes, I would like to know if there are any other methods to achieve the same thing (elegant, simple, pythonic) or if perhaps this is indeed the best solution?

My question arises from the fact that it seems possible that there may be an inbuilt method or some function that more efficiently retrieves the current index and searches for fields.....perhaps not though.

Thanks in advance for the discussion and any explanations that I will accept as answers.

Comment: This is not a great solution. For starters, you loop over all fields in the row when your ID is always stored in the first column, you don't have any message to alert the user if the ID is not found, and you restrict yourself to a single consistent ID lookup as you loop over the open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read it into a list or even better a dictionary in terms of look up time, and then simply use the following:

**if in l** or **if in d** (l or d being the list / dictionary respectively)

An interesting discussion however, on whether this would be the simplest method, or if your existing solution is.

**Dictionaries:**

```
   1 # retrieve the value for a particular key
   2 value = d[key]
```

A note on time complexity and efficiency in the use of dictionaries:

Python mappings must be able to, given a particular key object, determine which (if any) value object is associated with a given key. One simple approach would be to store a LIST of (key, value) pairs, and then search the list sequentially every time a value was requested. Immediately you can see that this would be very slow with a large number of items - in complexity terms, this algorithm would be O(n), where n is referring to the number of items in the mapping.

**Python's dictionary** is the answer here, although it isn't always te best solution - the implementation reduces the average complexity of dictionary lookups to O(1) by requiring that key objects provide a "hash" function. In your case and because structurally the data you are dealing with is not terribly complex, it may be easiest to stick to your existing solution, although a dictionary should certainly be considered if it is time efficiency you are after.

Comment: building a dictionary could be an interesting one, for several reasons, and then searching it in terms of 0(n) etc...

Answer (score 1):

If the list keeps this format you could access the field of the row by index to condense it a bit.

```
for row in studentfileReader:
    if row[0]==id:
        print(row[1]+" "+row[2])
```

it also avoids a match if the ID is not in the beginning but somewhere in between e.g. "Test1:002"

Comment: interesting. thank you. Is there such a feature where other users can vote on the best method. How could I possibly know what really is most pythonic and best?! Would your solution, print it for the corresponding iD? I'm assuming so, haven't tested.

Comment: I honestly can't answer you what is the most pythonic, just in this case a direct access seems more useful and also more safe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if there is such thing as a "pythonic" way of finding a record on a matching key, but here is an example that adds a couple interesting things over your own example and the other answers, like the use of generators, and comprehension. Besides, what is more pythonic than a one-liner.

`any` is a python built-in, it might interest you to know that it exists since it does exactly what you do.

```
with open("studentinfo.txt","r") as f:
    sid=input("Enter Id:")
    print any((line.split(",")[0] == sid for line in f.readlines()))
```

Comment: I like this - but for teaching/learning purposes struggle to interpret it easily (it isn't obvious in terms of analysing each line and explaining it). Thank you!

Comment: I agree, it is not something that should be forced bluntly over a beginner. But since you were mentionning teaching purpose, I thought it was interesting to bring in a few python key concepts :).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider using `csv.DictReader` for this usage, since you have tabular data with consistent columns.

If you only want to retrieve data once then you can simply iterate through the file until the first occurrence of the desired id, as follows;

```
import csv

def search_by_student_id(id):
    with open('studentinfo.txt','r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, ['id', 'surname', 'first_name'],
                                restkey='results')
        for line in reader:
            if line['id'] == id:
                return line['surname'], line['first_name']

print(search_by_student_id('001'))
# ('Joe', 'Bloggs')
```

If however, you plan on looking up entries from this data multiple times it would pay to create a dictionary, which is more expensive to create, but significantly reduces lookup times. Then you could look up data like this;

```
def build_student_id_dict():
    with open('studentinfo.txt','r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, ['id', 'surname', 'first_name'],
                                restkey='results')
        student_id_dict = {}
        for line in reader:
            student_id_dict[line['id']] = line['surname'], line['first_name']
        return student_id_dict

student_by_id_dict = build_student_id_dict()
print(student_by_id_dict['002'])
# ('Ash', 'Smith')
```